# List child records not linked to a given parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

What's the best way to find all child records who are not linked to a certain parent record via a many-to-many relationship? They can have any other parent, or none at all.

I'm trying things like this:

```
children = db.Children
  .Where(c => !c.Parents
     .Where(x => x.parentId == knownParentId)
     .Any())
  .ToList();
```

...it returns one record that I'm interested in but not others that I know exist (probably using 'Any' when I shouldn't be)

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, now I've just realised my database was out of date, and it seems that the code in my original post (where the 'Any' is at the end) also seems to give the correct results. I don't know if it's working 'by accident' though but anyone else reading this and having the same question might want to bear that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `All` extension method as follow:

```
children = db.Children.Where(c => c.Parents.All(x => x.parentId != knownParentId)).ToList();
```

Or you can still use `Any` extension method:

```
children = db.Children.Where(c => !c.Parents.Any(x => x.parentId == knownParentId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! Tried both and they both work - PC crashed part way through testing, hence my delay in replying sorry :-)